# How to clear cache memory on load of HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**I'm developing a website. But it caches user name and password in cache block which can be accessed using hacking software like winhex. I want to clear cache**

```
$(".object-position").livequery("change", function() {
    $("#objects-list input").attr('disabled', true);
    var action = $(this).attr('name');
    var position = $(this).attr('value');
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var model = id.split("-")[0];
    var object_id = id.split("-")[1];

    $("#loader").show();
    $("#loader").fadeIn(200);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "/manage/update_position/",
        data: "action=" + action + "&model=" + model + "&object_id=" + object_id + "&position=" + position,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $("#loader").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("#loader").hide();
            });
            $("objects-list").html(data["html"]);
            $("#message").show();
            $("#message").fadeIn(400).html('<span>'+data["message"]+'</span>');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#message").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("#message").hide();
                });
            }, 1500); 
        }
    });
    $("#objects-list input").attr("disabled", false);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: On deleting your browser's cache will remove this. And remove saved passwords.

Comment: but i wanna do it programatically

Comment: `autocomplete=off` ;)

Comment: how about adding headers for not saving cache?

Comment: its not working for my website

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This meta code should work with most browsers for web content. However, for resource files (javascript, images, css) your mileage may vary. Most cache busting strategies involve changing the name of your resource files (perhaps dynamically) or using Apache rewrite rules to pretend that the names are changed. This google search should put you on the right track.(cache busting strategy for js)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```